# How can I override MUI 5 input padding right?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI 5 and I want to update the input default padding right.

I have created a `CustomizedNativeSelect` and inside it I updated `MuiInputBase-input` padding. However, this new `padding-right` cannot override the default one.

Is there a way I can override the `padding-right` except using `inputProps` with `styles`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-pare-lrxeiv?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can change the padding in this way.

```
const CustomizedNativeSelect = styled(NativeSelect)`
 .MuiInputBase-input {
   padding: 10px 55px;
 }
 .css-1dmqq7i-MuiNativeSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input.css-1dmqq7i-MuiNativeSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input.css-1dmqq7i-MuiNativeSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input {
   padding-right: 100px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/) on the MUI component directly:

```
<NativeSelect
  value={3}
  sx={{
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingBottom: 2,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  }}
>
  {options}
</NativeSelect>;
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-worker-y8234c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just add && for override original style - `"&&.MuiInputBase-input"`

```
const CustomizedNativeSelect = styled(NativeSelect)`
  "&&.MuiInputBase-input" {
    padding: 10px 55px;
  }
`;
```

in theme looks like

```
MuiNativeSelect: {
  styleOverrides: {
     select: {
       '&&.MuiInputBase-input': {
          paddingRight: '5px'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```